# Block of tags becomes too narrow with the topbar addition

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, tags

I'm usually following a page with the list of tags using the "or" between them, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python%20or%20python-2.7%20or%20python-3.x%20or%20lxml%20or%20beautifulsoup).

Before the addition of the new top-bar, the block with the list of tags on the right had the same width with other blocks on the right side of the page.

Now, I suspect, because of the "Ask Question" button positional change, there is a lot of space to the right making the block with tags quite narrow:

[image]

Looks like the parent element of the "Ask Question" button is "eating up" the valuable space:

[image]

Is this by design or a UI bug/problem?

Comment: it's not quite a bug, it's more like a problem. we have some mess in sidebar's code that we need to figure out, but that's separate topic.. i will try to see what we can do here to fix the way tags are displayed. but i can't promise this will be done today or tomorrow..